# How to find files in Perforce using P4V?

Tags: user-interface, version-control, perforce

I have somewhere in huge perforce depot a file that starts from "Web" and ends with ".pdf" and it probably placed under //depot/main/.
How to find this file in Depot using P4V?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably easier finding using command line:

```
p4 files //depot/main/...Web*.pdf
```

Comment: Works, powerful! Thank you

Comment: Note that some examples on the internet put quotes around the filename, either double or single, but that did not work for me and produced various errors instead. Doing it without any quotes around the filename, as this answer shows, was necessary for me.

Comment: @Loduwijk omitting sparks `'` or rabbit ears `"` around the asterisk will, in a terminal shell, cause the shell to try to expand the argument to match files in the current working directory. So they *are* necessary.

Answer (score 4):

In P4V's left pane in the tab that is titled "Depot" you right-click on a depot and the select "Find file ...".
In the opening dialog you enter the depot tree in that you want to search the file and ".pdf" in the "Name contains:" field.
That should list all the ".pdf" files in the specified tree.

Comment: This does not work because it finds all huge list of pdf files and also all files that starts with Web.

Comment: You can adapt the arguments as needed.

Comment: This worked better for me than the "p4 files" command line which would only search a depot mapped to my workspace.

Comment: This is strange. I get the dialog alright, and I can populate a list of conditions for "Name matches any of the following:", but apart from the operator dropdown, there is nothing more. There is no text field where I could enter my operand. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `p4 files …` method worked fine for me. I did not specify a workspace, and I did not have any workspace p4 global variable set so I think there was no workspace mapping. @ChocoBilly